# Napkin custom LookAndFeel in Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

**Premise**

I'm pretty new to GUI programming but I'm looking for a way to put the Napkin Look and feel onto my application though Eclipse.

**What I've done thus far**

I've had a look around and from what I can see I need to put the napkin .jar's into my buildpath.  I've tried to do this by right-clicking in the navigator and selecting import --> File system and highlighting the .jars associated with Napkin.

Inside of my Main I've added the following code:

```
try{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which I believe should apply the Napkin Look and Feel, unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
    at yulfy.alterd.FrameTest.main(FrameTest.java:8)
```

**Question**

What on earth am I doing wrong? (I'm sorry if it's terribly obvious!)

Thanks for your time!

**Links**

Napkin site:
http://napkinlaf.sourceforge.net/

**Notes**

- It seems that the latest is 1.2 and not alpha001 which is the first
  file available on Sourceforge.
- If any further clarification/information is needed, don't hesitate to
  post.

Comment: try UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NapkinLookAndFeel());

Comment: @mulax I'm getting the following error from Eclipse: "NapkinLookAndFeel cannot be resolved to a type. "

Comment: if you can't import net.sourceforge.napkinlaf.NapkinLookAndFeel, your build path is wrong

Comment: @mulax Any particular recommendation on how to get it right? I've tried using the import function in Eclipse.  Other then that I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click over your project, go to build path, click on "add external jar" and select the jar

Comment: Worked like a charm, turns out I wasn't putting it into the build path.  Thanks for your help! For future viewers it's: Right-click project, properties, Java Build Path, Librarys, Add External jar.